# Why does adding a constant to an int8_t promote it to a larger type?

Tags: c++, integer, integer-promotion

In gcc, adding or subtracting a constant to an integral type smaller than `int` results in an `int`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int8_t wat = 5;
    printf("%zd\n", sizeof(wat + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

gives 4. I noticed this when using a simple `+=` statement with `-Wconversion`. With that warning flag set,

```
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    int8_t wat = 5;
    wat += 5;
    return 0;
}
```

gives

> wat.cpp:7:6: warning: conversion to ‘int8_t {aka signed char}’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]

Is there any way to suppress this warning? Why is this occuring? Casting doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Clang doesn't issue a warning in this case...

Comment: Not all integer numbers are `int`s..

Comment: Not just in GCC. The standard defines it as an integral promotion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 10 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. **The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result**. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,

The usual arithmetic conversion includes the integral promotion

> 1 A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or
>   wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of
>   int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

So in this expression

```
wat += 5;
```

that is equivalent to

```
wat = wat + 5;
```

`wat` in the right side of the assignment is converted to type `int` and the type of expression `wat + 5` is int. As the range of values of type `int` is greater than of type `int8_t` the compiler issues the warning.

Also the message of the warning shows how to suppress the warning:  **[-Wconversion]**